# Using return value from lambda expression scheme?

Tags: lambda, scheme, racket

I currently have a function that takes in a list of functions, and a list of words and applies each one of those functions to the list of words and compiles a list. I want to return a function that checks if a word is in that list with `#t` or `#f`, however I am unsure of how to do that and not being allowed to use set. Here is what I have so far to create the list:

```
(define list-checker
  (lambda (flist words)
    (cond
      ((null? flist) '())
      (else          (append (map (lambda(x) ((car flist) x)) words)
                             (list-checker (cdr flist) words))))))
```

Example usage: `((list-checker (list wordToScrambled wordToReverse) words) '(h e l l o))` should output either `#t` or `#f` where `wordToScrambled`, `wordToReverse` are functions, words is a list of words `'((h i)(h e l l o))`.

Comment: What is `gen-checker`? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on what you want the function to do. Can you provide an example of the desired behavior?

Comment: gen-checker is a typo sorry should have been list-checker. The function should work like:
((list-checker (list wordToScrambled wordToReverse) words) '(h e l l o))
In this example list-checker gets a list of two functions that scramble the words and reverse them, and a list of words. It should then return a function that checks if a given word is in the new list created by the passed in functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(define (list-checker flist words)
  (let ([transformed-words
         (append* (map (lambda (f) (map f words)) flist))])
    (lambda (word) (and (member word transformed-words) #t))))
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want to compose the functions and use that on each element and then return a fucntion that checks an argument if it's one of the translated value?

```
(define (get-list-checker fns lst)
  (define trans-lst (map (apply compose fns) lst))
  (lambda (e)
    (and (member e trans-lst) #t)))

(define test (get-list-checker (list add1 (λ (x) (* x x))) '(1 2 3)))
(test 10) ; ==> #t
(test 11) ; ==> #f
```